# Can a person have a “dextrous mind”?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage, metaphors, is-it-a-phrase

Can we say that a man has a *dextrous mind*?

This would mean that he has a highly skilled brain which is capable of excelling at a certain mental activity, or that he as an individual is capable of picking up new skills rather quickly.

I understand that the definition of dexterity is used to convey that a man is a fine craftsman or is capable of using his hands in intricate complex patterns.

Can we extend *dextrous* to refer to mental agility?

Comment: It's not at all common (especially compared to alternatives like [*an **agile** mind*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dextrous+mind%2Cagile+mind&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cagile%20mind%3B%2Cc0)), and it's usually spelt ***dexterous***, but why would you think there's anything "wrong" with [*dexterous mind*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dexterous+mind%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)?

Comment: I have to say to me it sounds **sort of wrong**. If you use it, it really just sounds like: you had another word in mind (simply agile or sharp), but you were "trying to use a fancy word, but picked the wrong one".  Does that make sense?  Note that (1) you can get the definition in a dictionary. (2) your definition in the SECOND paragraph is pretty close.  (3) your definition in the FIRST paragraph is wrong :)

Comment: if you literally want to say:  **capable of picking up new skills rather quickly** then 100% it's "agile" as Fumble sed.  Dextrous has no connection to "picking up new skills quickly".  A watchmaker who has been doing it for 40 years and is incredible at that --- and is utterly hopeless at other hand crafts, say woodworking, etc -- would be "dextrous". It has nothing to do with "picking up new skills easily".

Comment: The *mental* ability to understand new things quickly (or grasp novel concepts quickly, or solve problems quickly) is ***perspicacious***.

Comment: Or, erm, the *ability* is "perspicuity"; the *person* is "perspicacious".

Comment: @DanBron- I think the *ability* is perspicacity, the *quality* is perspicuity.

Comment: @DanBron `Perspicuity` refers to something that is clear and lucid,so to have a perspicious mind would mean that your thoughts are easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say someone who had a dextrous mind is:

> ***adroit*** : clever or skillful in using the hands or mind.

Both *dextrous* and *adroit* are rooted in the word *right*, because most people are right-handed, and so the right-hand is considered more skillful.

You could also say the person is ***clever***, a ***genius***, has ***ingenuity***, has ***wit*** (though in modern times, the sense of "humorous" has overtaken the older sense of "sharp"), is ***perspicacious*** (if you wanted to emphasize his ability to perceive or understand *quickly*), is ***shrewd*** or ***astute*** (if you wanted to underscore his ability to turn things to his own advantage), or ***intelligent***, ***smart***, ***sharp***, or any number of synonyms that don't necessarily entail mental *agility*.

Comment: For voters: please note that this answer was posted when the question was "what is *a good word* to describe someone with a dextrous mind", rather than "is a '*having a dextrous mind*' a legitimate usage", as it reads now (after recent edits).